# p values and significance in RLM (MASS package) R

Tags: r, regression, p-value, robust

I'm running some regression analyses and got pretty confused about R's output when it comes to robust regression models.
When I run a `OLS` -- using the command `lm()` -- I get this as output:

> Coefficients:
>
> ```
>                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
> ```

But when I run a robust linear model using the `rlm()` command, the output looks like so:

> Coefficients:
>
> ```
>                 Value   Std. Error t value
> ```

How do I get  the `p-values` and the significance-levels in an `rlm` then? Without that, the whole analysis is somewhat pointless.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer to that anywhere, so I hope someone around here can help me out. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: add some data you model, add the model you test, read that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example]

Answer (score 13):

The `sfsmisc` package offers a helpful function for conducting a Wald test:

```
library(MASS)
library(sfsmisc)
summary(rsl <- rlm(stack.loss ~ ., stackloss))
#Call: rlm(formula = stack.loss ~ ., data = stackloss)
#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-8.91753 -1.73127  0.06187  1.54306  6.50163 
#
#Coefficients:
#            Value    Std. Error t value 
#(Intercept) -41.0265   9.8073    -4.1832
#Air.Flow      0.8294   0.1112     7.4597
#Water.Temp    0.9261   0.3034     3.0524
#Acid.Conc.   -0.1278   0.1289    -0.9922
#
#Residual standard error: 2.441 on 17 degrees of freedom

f.robftest(rsl, var = "Air.Flow")
#   robust F-test (as if non-random weights)
#
#data:  from rlm(formula = stack.loss ~ ., data = stackloss)
#F = 50.879, p-value = 1.677e-06
#alternative hypothesis: true Air.Flow is not equal to 0

f.robftest(rsl, var = "Acid.Conc.")
#   robust F-test (as if non-random weights)
#
#data:  from rlm(formula = stack.loss ~ ., data = stackloss)
#F = 1.0447, p-value = 0.3211
#alternative hypothesis: true Acid.Conc. is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Roland! That helps a lot. It still makes me wonder if that is the only way to do it - it feels a bit like a workaround since I think the significance is an important aspect of the regression output. Are there other commands that provide the significance for all coefficients more conveniently?  Thanks again for your answer and your help!

Comment: "since I think the significance is an important aspect of the regression output" Many statisticians disagree.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Hints to certain books, chapters or papers would also be appreciated, since I really want to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your link. I still wonder if there is a way of getting a regression table that includes conveniently the significance, like in an OLS. I can't imagine that this is such a unusual idea that nobody ever wanted that before, too.

Comment: This answer answers your question "How do I get the p-values and the significance-levels in an rlm then?"--you might consider accepting the answer! If you wish this were a general feature, you could make a request to the maintainers of `MASS` or write a function to incorporate the tests you want (e.g., as `lmerTest` does for `lme4`)

Comment: Can anyone comment on whether the standard inferential framework actually works out of the box for robust linear models, or whether these are omitted because the theoretical justification for using the standard approach is weak ... ?

Comment: @Roldand Can you provide any papers on how the wald test is constructed for the robust coefficients?

Comment: Following up on @BenBolker comment I found this useful. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/108659.html