# robust regression coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, robust, robust-standard-error

I ran a robust regression using the rlm package but I see that p-value of the coefficients are not returned. What is the best way to test the coefficients returned from rlm for significance?

I was looking at the rlm function here:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/robust-regression/

pvalue are not returned:

```
summary(rr.huber <- rlm(crime ~ poverty + single, data = cdata))
## 
## Call: rlm(formula = crime ~ poverty + single, data = cdata)
## Residuals:
##    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
## -846.1 -125.8  -16.5  119.2  679.9 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Value     Std. Error t value  
## (Intercept) -1423.037   167.590     -8.491
## poverty         8.868     8.047      1.102
## single        168.986    17.388      9.719
## 
## Residual standard error: 182 on 48 degrees of freedom
```

Thank you.

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205614/p-values-and-significance-in-rlm-mass-package-r ?

Comment: Can you provide any papers on how the wald test is constructed for the robust coefficients?